# Oracle stored procedure execution using PHP

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-call-interface

The below code snippet is a stored procedure(in oracle) execution using php. I'm getting

***Failed SP execution***

always. Can you guys findout what the problem is? I'm new to the oracle with php.

```
<?php
echo "<pre>TESTING ORACLE CONNECTION";
$conn = oci_connect("user", "pass", "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=some ip)(PORT=port))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=some name)(INSTANCE_NAME=some name)))");
if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo "<br/><br/>".$m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
else {
    echo "<br/><br/>Connected to Oracle!";
    echo "<br/><br/>TESTING STORED PROCEDURE:a_proc";
    $sql = 'BEGIN a_proc(:in_param1,:out_param2); END;';
    $stmt_id = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
    $value1=1235;
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt_id, ':param1', $value1);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt_id, ':out_param2', $out_message);
    $res=oci_execute($stmt_id);
    if(!$res){
        echo "<br/><br/>Failed SP execution".oci_error();    
    }
    print_r($out_message);
}
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: don't output a fixed/useless error message when you could be output the actual reason for failure. try `echo "Failed... " . oci_error($stmt_id)` or whatever.

Comment: used `oci_error($stmt_id)`/`oci_error()` but same result!